# How to make an object change speed based on where it hits another object?

Tags: java, performance, processing, pong

MIN_SPEED when the ball hits the centre of the paddle, to MAX_SPEED when the ball hits the edge of a paddle, and it should change smoothly in 
between."

I have been tasked with doing this and for the life of me can't figure it out. The objective of the assignment is to simulate a pong game. And when the ball hits a part of the paddle it will either speed up or slow down.
Please go easy on me this is my first computer science class and its kicking my ass.

Already tried making an if statement, and looking into processing's references.

```
void bouncePaddle(){
if(ballPOSx -10 >= 0 && ballPOSx -10 <= 0 + paddleWidth && ballPOSy >= paddleY && ballPOSy <= paddleY + paddleHeight){
  BOUNCE2 = true;
  ballDirection = random(PI/4,(7*PI/4));
  ball_x_speed = cos(ballDirection);
  }
}
if(ballPOSx + 10>= width-20 && ballPOSx +10 <= width-20 + paddleWidth && ballPOSy >= paddle2Y && ballPOSy <= paddle2Y + paddleHeight){
  BOUNCE2 = true;
  ballDirection = random((3*PI/4),(5*PI/4));  
  ball_y_speed = sin(ballDirection);
}
}
```

PaddleY = left paddle and the y coordinate of it moving up and down the canvas
PaddleY2 = right paddle

The size of the ball is 10, so I subtracted 10 to make it actually hit the paddle on the edge instead of the center

Comment: Since you already know how to determine where the ball has hit, just use a thread to slowly move from current speed to desired speed. Let me know in which block of code you want to increase speed and in which you want to decrease and i'll guide you

Comment: The first if statement is the paddle on the left, and the second if statement is the paddle on the right. So im guessing both if statements need this inside after a "BOUNCE" occurs. @KhalilKabara

Comment: Pro tip: write it down on paper, THEN implement it in code. One thing at a time. If I had to write the logic here, I would probably go like this: 1- Check for collision between paddle and ball  2- Check the position of the ball relative to the paddle so I know where it hits it  3- Change the ball speed according to the position in #2